# Load model in keras

Tags: keras, deep-learning, lstm

When loading a model (previously processed) into LSTM network in the keras API will it include training data (Explicitly) in the network?

And if not, how does this gonna  **(load model)** help to predict a pattern in time series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When loading a model (previously processed) into LSTM network in the
>   keras API will it include training data (Explicitly) in the network?

No `model.save()` is designed to exclude the training data in the saved file.
Most of the time you save your model after training for prediction. In the prediction case you don't need your original data anymore, because the model predicts based on the trained weights which are saved with the model, which is basically a list of layers defining your model. `model.summary()` describe the information which keras have about the model pretty good.

> And if not, how does this gonna (load model) help to predict a pattern
>   in time series.

`model.save()` save basicaly two things:

1. Your model (basically the layer objects and their relation)
2. The weights belonging to each layer in your model.

The weights of the model are the product of your Training is the "knowledge" your model achieved during training and this what is necessary to predict new samples.

Comment: Well explained @dennis-ec. And one more doubt is whether validation data is important or test data is important or else both data is necessary for training ?

Comment: Validation data is needed for training. You need an independent data set to validate your training on and ensure you don't overtrain too much. 

Because you determine the end point of your training with the validation set, it's not completely unrelated to the training.

So in order to test your model on a completely unrelated dataset you need the test dataset. This data set must not be used during training.

Answer (score 3):

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras_contrib.losses import import crf_loss
from keras_contrib.metrics import crf_viterbi_accuracy

# To save model
model.save('my_model_01.hdf5')

# To load the model
custom_objects={'CRF'                 : CRF,
              'crf_loss'            : crf_loss,
              'crf_viterbi_accuracy': crf_viterbi_accuracy}

# To load a persisted model that uses the CRF layer 
model1 = load_model("/home/abc/my_model_01.hdf5", custom_objects = custom_objects)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the goal of any neural network (CNN, LSTM or others) is to learn from train data (calculating wheights) and generalize to any data (of the same problem). So you just need to load the architecture of the network and the wheights.

In keras the easy way is to save/load the architecture and wheights with:

```
model.save('my_model.hdf5')

model.load('my_model.hdf5')
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Marcelo Queirós